# Testing Auto-renewing in-app purchase in sandbox environment

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, storekit, auto-renewing

I have an app in which, content is uploaded on weekly basis and hence using Auto-renewing subscriptions is the best option. Once the user subscribes for a weekly subscription, he is  charged on weekly basis until he opts out.

I researched on how to unsubscribe and I read there is no api call or no other way to implement this from the app. The user has to manually turn it off from iTunes & App Store. Is that true ?

Question: I am testing with a sandbox account so is there a way to Manage subscriptions  i.e stop subscription to that particular app? I want to turn off the weekly subscription and then try again to turn it on from app. I could not turn it off from device. So is it because I am using sandbox account?

Please reply! Thanks in advance!